# Message box on delete link of a closed post

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

I asked a question and it got the reply, and post voted Closed I thought to delete the post(because it was really bad) but I get the message something like

> Due to the possibilities of duplicate post you can delete it after two days.

and after two days when I try to delete the post, It prompt saying:

> [image: message]

So my concern is if a post has answer and it can not be deleted even after two days, then message prompt should be updated to the above(image) one. As first one is giving a wrong message which user came to know after two days.

Or we can also remove or disabled the delete link,if the delete is not allowed for post.

#### Edit

The post was closed when first time I tried to delete the post with some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the post didn't have answers until after you first tried to delete it?  If it just had a comment at that time, then both messages are valid.

Comment: No!! it has the answer.

Comment: But did it have an answer when you first tried to delete it, or did you try to delete it before someone answered?

Comment: as I said in post I got the two replies after sometime I tried to delete

Comment: ok but post was closed on that time...

Comment: Sounds like an algorithm was in play that checked to see if the post was closed, and if so you get Response 1.  You went back to delete the second time, and it saw you had answers so you got Response 2.  I'd say the code is working as intended.